# How to use the same POD in const and non-const contexts?

Tags: c++, constants

The initial problem is that I have some data to save and retrieve from plate and would like to use a helper struct in the following way:

```
// this is how I want to use my struct for saving
void safeData()
{
  Data data;
  data.name = getNameToSave(); // returns const char*
  save(data);
}

// ... and in the same way for writing.
void readData()
{
  Data data;
  read(data);
  use(data);
}
```

... whereas

```
struct Data
{
  const char* name;

  // potentially many more data members
}
```

I'm bound to (const) char* instead of std::string for now because this should be used with legacy code. Unfortunately this will bring up a constness problem:

```
void read(Data& data)
{
  // initial legacy free
  free(data.name); // warning: can't convert from const char* to void*

  // fill with some data
  data.name = getNameFromPlate();
}
```

So the thing is this: Since my data retrieval methods for reading like getNameFromSomewhere returns const char* I'm bound to making my struct members const, too. This however clashes with write-usage because in this case they must be non-const. What is the best and cleanest way to work around this?

Comment: Are you sure `getNameToSave` returns a `const char *` that you are supposed to `free`? If so you just have to `const_cast` the `const` away no matter what you do, because it is required to `free` the pointer. But chances are they gave you a pointer to a static buffer and you are not supposed to actually `free` it.

Comment: No, getNameToSave owns the pointer. In this case Data only references the pointer without taking ownership, only in the case of reading data it becomes the owner. That's part of the (ownership) problem.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is for the `Data` struct to **own** the `name` data. So when you assign to it you should allocate memory and do a memcpy. This is the only way to make sure that a) you don't leak memory b) the data is not freed before you are done with it and c) data is not changed by other processes in the mean time.

Since you do a copy anyway, you can probably make it more manageable by using std::string instead of `const char*`. When you assign for `const char*`, std::string will do the copy for you and you can get a `const  char*` back with `c_str()`, so that you can still work with the legacy architecture. You don't have to do the switch but will make it easier to manage in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You have not only a problem of constness, but also a problem of ownership. Except if the API states that the return value of `getNameToSave()` has to be freed by caller after use, you should **not** free it. While when you read it from a file, you **must** free it.

So the simpler way is to always use a local copy that you consistently free after use. As you are required to use old `const char *` instead of `std::string` you'd better keep using the good old C library function. Here the best function is `strdup` that automagically allocate memory and copy old string into it.

An alternative way would be to store the status of the member `Data::name` in a boolean member :

```
struct Data
{
  const char* name;
  bool dyn; // must be freed if true

  // potentially many more data members
}
```

You can then safely use:

```
if (data.dyn && (data.name != nullptr)) {
    free(const_cast<char *>(data.name);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is true and I should have elaborated more on this. What however if the struct also contains bigger data types like matrices or images where we don't want to make unnecessary copies?